# Extension of $FP_{n}$ group

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, geometric-group-theory, group-cohomology

I am reading a paper (*[Finitely presented residually free groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3704)* by Bridson, Howie, Miller III, and Short, Theorem 5.2) where they write the following:

Since $S_{0}$ is a group of type $FP_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$ and there is a series $$S_{0}\triangleleft S_{1}\triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft S_{l}=T$$ where each $S_{i+1}/S_{i}$ is finite or infinite cyclic, then by the obvious induction, $T$ is of type $FP_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$.

I understand that if $S_{i+1}/S_{i}$ is finite and $S_{i}$ of type $FP_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$, then so is $S_{i+1}$, because that property is inherited in finite extensions. Nevertheless, I really can't prove the same when $S_{i+1}/S_{i}$ is infinite cyclic.

Why is this true? Maybe it does not always hold, but in my case yes: I am working in direct products of limit groups, so $S_{0}$ is a full subdirect product of limit groups, $S_{0}\leq \Gamma_{1}\times \cdots \times \Gamma_{n}$.

Comment: What is the paper?  Or, at least, what is a group of type $\operatorname{FP}_n(\mathbb Q)$?

Comment: @LSpice this is a standard finiteness property of group cohomology. One says that $G$ has Property $FP_n(R)$ if the trivial $RG$-module $R$ has a resolution by projective $RG$-modules $P_n\to P_{n-1}\to\dots P_0\to R\to 0$ with each $P_i$ finitely generated. See [Wikipedia: finiteness properties of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finiteness_properties_of_groups)

Comment: @YCor, ah, fair enough.  Still it’s appropriate to mention the paper!

Comment: @tj_ Sorry, I do not understand your counterexample. $C\times C$ is finitely presentable, that is, of type $F_{2}$, so in particular it is of type $FP_{2}(\mathbb{Q})$, and so it is of type $FP_{1}(\mathbb{Q})$. I am not saying that my group $T$ can't be of type $FP_{n+1}(\mathbb{Q})$, only that we can ensure that it is $FP_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: @LSpice The paper is 'Finitely presented residually free groups', http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.210.3212&rep=rep1&type=pdf , Thm 5.2

Comment: Note: the result is trivial for $n=1$, since $FP_1(Q)$ means finitely generated. It can also be checked to be true for $n=2$, using that a group is $FP_2(Q)$ iff is isomorphic to $G/N$ for some finitely presented group group $G$ and some normal subgroup $N$ such that $N/[N,N]$ is torsion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $0\to A \to B \to C\to 0$ is a short exact sequence of groups and $A$, $C$ are of type $FP_{n}$, then so is $B$. Reference: Proposition 2.2 in *Homological finiteness properties of fibre products* by Kochloukova and Ferreira Lima ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03759)).